# How to count occurrence of a particular value in the columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset as shown below:

```
df

          cp.city cp.state cp.birth_date cp.age cp.gender cp.education_level cp.occupation
1          Savage       MN    1986-04-29     29         F               NULL          NULL
2        Coventry       RI    1965-12-19     NULL       F               NULL          NULL
3            NULL     NULL    1993-06-24     21         M               NULL          NULL
4     Baton Rouge       LA    1991-12-29     NULL       M               NULL          NULL
5          Tucson       AZ    1955-03-20     60         F               NULL          NULL
6         Atlanta       GA    1964-01-18     21         M               NULL          NULL
7  Sheffield Lake       OH    1956-12-27     61         F               NULL          NULL
8       Ypsilanti       MI    1991-04-26     23         F               NULL          NULL
9            NULL     NULL          NULL     49         M               NULL          NULL
10           NULL     NULL    1943-05-31     70         M               NULL          NULL
11           NULL     NULL          NULL     22         M               NULL          NULL
12           NULL     NULL    1960-12-23     54         M               NULL          NULL
13       New York       NY    1973-03-29     42         NULL            NULL          NULL
14           NULL     NULL    1960-07-12     54         M               NULL          NULL
15           NULL     NULL    1957-02-25     58         F               NULL          NULL
16      Brunswick       GA    1962-12-17     51         M               NULL          NULL
17         Savage       MN    1986-07-12     29         M               NULL          NULL
18           NULL     NULL    1985-09-27     29         M               NULL          NULL
19   Prairieville       LA    1986-01-25     28         M               NULL          NULL
   cp.contact_channel cp.language_preferred cpss.optin_language_id
1             Website                   ENG                     40
2             Website                   ENG                     40
3                NULL                  NULL                     40
4             Website                  NULL                     40
5             Website                   ENG                     40
6               Other                   ENG                     40
7             Website                   ENG                     40
8             Website                  NULL                     40
9                NULL                  NULL                     40
10               NULL                  NULL                     40
11               NULL                  NULL                     40
12               NULL                  NULL                     40
13            Website                   ENG                     40
14               NULL                  NULL                     40
15               NULL                  NULL                     40
16            Website                   ENG                     40
17            Website                   ENG                     40
18               NULL                  NULL                     40
19            Website                  NULL                     40
```

I am looking to calculate the frequency & proportion of `NULL` occurrence in each column in a possible output table as shown below:

```
variable   freq  proportion
cp.city     2       0.01
cp.state    4       0.03
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.null(x)))`. This gives the proportions. Then it's a simple matter of computing the proportions.

Comment: Odd. I've never been able to get a `NULL` in a column like that, `data.frame(a=1:3, b=list(NULL,NULL,NULL))` fails for me. Is that an "R" `NULL` or is that the literal string `"NULL"`? (@RuiBarradas, your function on that sample data for me returns all `0`, which is consistent with no `NULL` in a (normal) frame.)

Comment: i think it is a string not the logical NULL

Comment: @r2evans I have tested my `sapply` with `NA`'s, couldn't do it with `NULL`'s. Also, in my first comment I obviously meant "This gives the *frequencies*."

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes, but unless there's something really weird going on, `sum(is.null(x))` will always be 0. (Yes, I tested with `NA` and your methodology is fine given the assumption of `NULL`s in a frame, which is apparently not the case. Not knocking the approach, changing it to `sum(x=="NULL")` is comparable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rui Barradas still had the right idea no matter if it's an "actual" `NULL` or a string. To give you a complete example how this could work:

```
> df <- data.frame(foo = c(1,"NULL",3,4), bar= c("a","NULL","NULL","d"))
> 
> freq <- sapply(df,function(x) sum(ifelse(x=="NULL",1,0)))
> 
> prop <- freq/nrow(df)
> 
> cbind(freq, prop)
    freq prop
foo    1 0.25
bar    2 0.50
```

Note: coming up with this answer I found this [article on the difference](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Working_with_NULL_NA_and_NaN/)  between `NULL`,`NA` and `NaN` in R:

> Note that NULL is different from the other two. NULL means that there is no value, while NA and NaN mean that there is some value, although one that is perhaps not usable.

This might also explain why you are not able to initialize a `data.frame` with `NULL` values in it, as I and apparently others discovered while trying to answer this question.

Comment: Instead of `ifelse`, when you want `0` and `1` use `as.integer(condition)`, it's orders of magnitude faster. Upvote.

Comment: 1) you learn something new everyday, thank you!
2) doesn't this depend on which proportion is needed here? Dividing by `sum(freq)` will tell you how that frequency compares to all other frequencies/columns. I assumed OP wanted to know the proportion for each column (i.e. percentage of `NULL` in that column). Both numbers are probably interesting to look at, depending on your ultimate goal with the data.

Comment: Yes, you are right about point 2). That is why I have deleted it.